# How do I combine the results of 3 queries into one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union

I have 3 queries that output the same style of result. Each query follows the same structure.

Tables Used in the Query:

- registration_database:

contains the unique id numbers for the people who registered to take a survey who were not previously registered to take the survey [column: registration] (joins with statefileid)

- statefileid:

contains unique id numbers for a large group of people that [column: 'statefileid'] and has information about what their favorite color is [column: 'favcolor']

- 2016data:

contains statefileid values for everyone who took a survey in 2016. Has a [column: electronic] which indicates if the person took the survey electronically 'Y' or in person 'N' (Logically everyone who did not take the survey electronically must have taken the survey in person

- 2018data:

same as 2016data except for it has information on everyone who took the survey in 2018

- 2020data:

same as 2020data except for it has information on everyone who took the survey in 2020

public_scores_2020: contains a statefileid column to join to the other tables and a [column: lrsupport] which gives a predictive score from 1-100 whether they are likely to support the direction left (100) or if they support the direction right (1)

Query 1:

```
select
case when favcolor='r' then 'Red'
               when favcolor='b' then 'Blue'
               when favcolor='g' then 'Green'
               when favcolor='y' then 'Yellow'
               when favcolor='o' then 'Orange'
               when favcolor='u' then 'Unknown Fav Color'
               when favcolor='w' then 'White'
               else 'Unknown Fav Color' end as "Favorite_Color"
,round(sum((lrsupport)/100),0) as "left"
,round(sum((1-(lrsupport)/100)),0) as "right"
,count(registration) AS "new_registered"
FROM registration_database
left join
statefileid
on registration=statefileid
join 2016data AS a
using (statefileid)
left join public_scores_2020
using(statefileid)
where a.electronic = 'N'
group by 1
order by 1
```

Query 2:

```
select
case when favcolor='r' then 'Red'
               when favcolor='b' then 'Blue'
               when favcolor='g' then 'green'
               when favcolor='y' then 'yellow'
               when favcolor='o' then 'orange'
               when favcolor='u' then 'Unknown Fav Color'
               when favcolor='w' then 'White'
               else 'Unknown Fav Color' end as "Favorite_Color"
,round(sum((lrsupport)/100),0) as "left"
,round(sum((1-(lrsupport)/100)),0) as "right"
,count(registration) AS "new_registered"
FROM registration_database
left join
statefileid
on registration=statefileid
join 2018data AS a
using (statefileid)
left join public_scores_2020
using(statefileid)
where a.electronic = 'N'
group by 1
order by 1
```

Query 3:

```
select
case when favcolor='r' then 'Red'
               when favcolor='b' then 'Blue'
               when favcolor='g' then 'green'
               when favcolor='y' then 'yellow'
               when favcolor='o' then 'orange'
               when favcolor='u' then 'Unknown Fav Color'
               when favcolor='w' then 'White'
               else 'Unknown Fav Color' end as "Favorite_Color"
,round(sum((lrsupport)/100),0) as "left"
,round(sum((1-(lrsupport)/100)),0) as "right"
,count(registration) AS "new_registered"
FROM registration_database
left join
statefileid
on registration=statefileid
join 2020data AS a
using (statefileid)
left join public_scores_2020
using(statefileid)
where a.electronic = 'N'
group by 1
order by 1
```

The output for each table query looks like this, this is for the query that referenced 2016data
[image: The output for each table query looks like this, this is for the query that referenced 2016data]

I am trying to combine the output of the 3 queries so that I can still get results ordered by favorite color rows= red, blue, green, etc. with 9 columns: 2016left, 2016right, 2016new_registered, 2018left, 2018right, 2018new_registered,2020left, 2020right, 2020new_registered.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: could you pleas use this - Please replace qry2016 using your query1 and so on. `select 
q1.Favorite_Color,
q1.left 2016left, q1.right 2016right,q1.new_registered 2016new_registered
q2.left 2018left, q2.right 2018right,q2.new_registered 2018new_registered
q3.left 2020left, q3.right 2020right,q3.new_registered 2020new_registered
from qry2016 q1 left join qry2018 q2 on q2.Favorite_Color=q1.Favorite_Color
left join qry2020 q3 on q3.Favorite_Color=q1.Favorite_Color order by 1
`

Comment: First thing you should do to **really** fix this is not to have several tables for the same entity. There should only be on table `data` with an extra column for the year.

Comment: And further to what sticky bit said use `sum` and `count` with `filter (where year = 20xx)` clause for the aggregated columns.

Comment: @stickybit unfortunately I don't have permission to create a new table that combines the columns in 2016data, 2018data, and 2020data. Do you have any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: @NickLal
`create view years_data as
select 2016 as year, * from 2016data
union all
select 2018 as year, * from 2018data
union all
select 2020 as year, * from 2020data`
and so on if there are more years.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the tables that are split by year using common table expressions then this will reduce the complexity of the query. This is just a example, it may not work without further effort:

```
with all_data as (
        select statefileid, lrsupport, electronic, 2016 as Year
        from 2016data
        union all
        select statefileid, lrsupport, electronic, 2018 as Year  
        from 2018data
        union all
        select statefileid, lrsupport, electronic, 2020 as Year
        from 2020data
        )

SELECT
  CASE
               when stf.favcolor='r' then 'Red'
               when stf.favcolor='b' then 'Blue'
               when stf.favcolor='g' then 'green'
               when stf.favcolor='y' then 'yellow'
               when stf.favcolor='o' then 'orange'
               when stf.favcolor='u' then 'Unknown Fav Color'
               when stf.favcolor='w' then 'White'
               else 'Unknown Fav Color'
  end as "Favorite_Color"
, count(case when a.year = 2016 then reg.registration end) AS "new_registered_2016"
, count(case when a.year = 2018 then reg.registration end) AS "new_registered_2018"
, count(case when a.year = 2020 then reg.registration end) AS "new_registered_2020"
FROM registration_database AS reg
INNER JOIN statefileid AS stf ON reg.registration = stf.statefileid
INNER JOIN all_data AS a ON stf.statefileid = a.statefileid
LEFT JOIN public_scores_2020 AS score ON stf.statefileid = score.statefileid
WHERE a.electronic = 'N'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Please also use table names or aliases when referring to columns throughout the query and I also recommend using more explicit joins to help with that. I think the join to table statefileid  could be an inner join